# Unable to load application.properties file @DataJpaTest annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-boot-test

i am trying to load the application.properties in spring boot project for testing . i am using @DataJpaAnnotation along with the my custom application.properties file.

Here is my sample configuration looks like

```
@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = {
                "classpath:sql/dont-use-cascadeType-remove/before.sql" }),
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = {
                "classpath:sql/dont-use-cascadeType-remove/after.sql" }) })
@TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@Slf4j
public class BookCategoryRepositoryTest {
```

i am able to execute test cases successfully but when i verified the logs
my application is taking the embeded H2 Db URL not the one which i mentioned
in application.properties file.

From the logs i found

```
embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:69b49362-3f83-4e79-9f35-b0deb5e744f2;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

my property file contains

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:p6spy:mem:jpa-best-practices;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=db-user
spring.datasource.password=db-password
```

not sure why its happening and i am unable to find the solution. please help.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to annotate your test with

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

as [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test).